# T-SQL check to see if date in one table is between two dates in another table then set value

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have two tables shown below. I want to create a new variable (VALUE) based on the logic below and show results in a 3rd table? How can I do this in T SQL?

**TABLE_1**

```
ID, DATE
```

**TABLE_2**

```
ID, DATE1, DATE2
```

Logic to set `VALUE`:

```
FOR ALL TABLE_1.ID

      IF TABLE_1.DATE IS BETWEEN TABLE_2.DATE1 AND TABLE_2.DATE2 
         THEN VALUE = 1 
         ELSE VALUE = 0

      IF TABLE_1.ID NOT IN TABLE_2 
         THEN VALUE = NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for the question edit. This flows much better.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to see the results for all rows where `table_1.id = table_2.id` (and `table_1` rows that do not have a match on `id`), then we can use a `left join` and a `case` expression:

```
select 
    t.id
  , t.date
  , IsBetween = case 
      when t.date between t2.Date1 and t2.Date2
        then 1
      when t2.id is null
        then null
      else 0
      end
  , t2.*
from table_1 as t
  left join table_2 as t2 
    on t.id = t2.id
```

If you only want one row for each row in `table_1`, and want to know if `table_1.data` is between any corresponding row in `table_2` or not, then we can use a `outer apply` to `select top 1` and a `case` expression:

```
select 
    t.id
  , t.date
  , IsBetween = case 
          when t.date between x.Date1 and x.Date2
            then 1
          when x.id is null
            then null
          else 0
          end
from table_1 t
  outer apply (
    select top 1 t2.*
    from table_2 t2
    order by case 
      when t.date between t2.Date1 and t2.Date2 
        then 0
      else 1
      end
  ) as x
```

Comment: Plus1 for deciphering the question.

Comment: Very well articulated. +1

Comment: My apologies for the long response time. Just getting back online. This works great. I used the first code for my issue. Thank you.